# Reverse Engineering Firmware Aether Cone

Tags: firmware, arm, binwalk

I have been trying to work out if its possible to reverse engineer the firmware for the Aether Cone. This is a good sound quality WIFI and Bluetooth speaker, but with Aether going bust, there is no support only a final firmware that enabled spotify.

What Information I currently know:

- CPU MCIMX6L3DVN10AB Arm Cortex A9:
  https://www.nxp.com/part/MCIMX6L3DVN10AB
- Storage 4G Sandisk:
  https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/NYUMNKWYff1QtBte.huge
- Board images:
  https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Aether+Cone+Speaker+Disassembly/102058
- Firmware: This can be got from the GitHub page as a .morse file.
  https://github.com/AetherThings/AetherCone/wiki

Investigation:
I have tried using binwalk to examine and extract the files but I have had limited success.

```
$ binwalk FRM000104.03.01.0013.morse

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION`

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

27842795      0x1A8D8EB       StuffIt Deluxe Segment (data): f
30729686      0x1D4E5D6       MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 7
57321984      0x36AAA00       POSIX tar archive, owner user name: "ader.img"
```

I have extracted the firmware to give this:

```
ls -larth _FRM000104.03.01.0013.morse-0.extracted/
total 29M
-rw-rw-r--  1    500   501   27 Oct  2  2015 version.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1    500   501  256 Oct  2  2015 signature.sha256
-rwxr-xr-x  1    500   501   12 Oct  2  2015 pre-inst.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1    500   501  184 Oct  2  2015 post-inst.sh
-r--r-----  1    500   501 1.9K Oct  2  2015 cert.pem
-rw-rw-r--  1    500   501   31 Oct  2  2015 bootloader.ver
-rw-rw-r--  1    500   501 221K Oct  2  2015 bootloader.img
-rw-r--r--  1    root  root 29M Sep  8 08:06 1A8D8EB.sit
-rw-r--r--  1    root  root 231K Sep 8 08:07 36AAA00.tar
```

If I try and read these, there is nonsense. So I tried using strings, but I cannot get anything useful out of this:

```
# strings version.txt
# strings post-inst.sh
    ^       Gj
    p8-wR
# strings pre-inst.sh
# strings signature.sha
256
=DHri,
Z@pH
A9!J8a
# strings cert.pem
W69)
fPq2
:)M7
vj%<u
)s|5
];DE
OEFvD(
C"s6m
-T}1
Jjw-
FkY'
(Z4G
bf<`
]*$+
?j[\
CVBG
p%XMi
|[q:
1nQ^
NAf&
' f&K
pt[679
# strings bootloader.ver
```

I would appreciate some assistance as I have definitely run out of ideas and talent now. My main aim would be to either get the root password as ssh is open on the device or be able to edit the firmware file to allow root so that I can update packages and hopefully keep this thing alive, people have had issues with the spotify connect plugin not working with more recent spotify versions.

Comment: You are out of luck. All the extracted files are encrypted.

Comment: Hi, How is it that the file names aren't encrypted but the rest of the content is encrypted?

Comment: What do file names and other file attributes have to do with the *contents* of files? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117325/where-are-filenames-stored-on-a-filesystem

Comment: I can play streams with mpg123 and gst-play-1.0 on the speaker.
it can be run it remotly with `ssh root@192.168.1.183 gst-play-1.0 http://stream_address`
I also installed(unpacked and symlinked) mpd found in a [thread on volumio forum](https://community.volumio.org/t/mpd-0-21-16-for-volumio-arm-armv7-and-x86/11554)
I could not get it work with alsa and after lot of hacking I got it streaming the music and then I start gst-play with my local address
`gst-play-1.0 http://localhost:8000`
now all works - its a bit hacky and I dont like the local streaming but it works

Answer (score 2):

as my previous answer was deleted (I'm guessing because it was not an answer per se) I've got more of an answer for you.

the firmware does nothing to stop you from using UART to interact with it except require a login.
root login is enabled for such an endeavor and you already have the password in the buildroot.config file.
from there you'll need to dig into the location of sshd_config as I'm not sure its in a standard place.
Add a line in the Authentication section of the file that says "PermitRootLogin yes".
Restart SSH server with "service sshd restart"

the firmware has an inserting security feature as it's using MetFS to encrypt the data.
the password for this is also available on the device in the sysupdate script if you want to tinker with a firmware update to enable ssh or when airplay2 is available go multi-room with a few of these speakers.

Answer (score 0):

my findings on openwrt forum
https://forum.openwrt.org/t/aether-cone-good-device-for-hacking/73890
also a link to the update script which can be helpful to see how to decode the firmware from github: https://pastebin.com/SXASpfnX

Comment: Answers on stack exchange sites are required to have stand-alone content, they may not simply be links to elsewhere.  For this to qualify, you'll need to summarize some independently useful set of your findings in the answer itself; then you can leave the rest to the links.